# CSV import undefined data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm having an issue with a .csv import for d3. I have been following

http://www.d3noob.org/2014/02/how-to-import-data-from-csv-file-with.html
http://www.d3noob.org/2013/03/d3js-force-directed-graph-example-basic.html

as templates for a csv import.**The Problem:** I cannot seem to access any of my csv columns. When I try and access a column, I get undefined. Specifically, I was attempting use this code as an example which to build my code off of.

```
d3.csv("data/force.csv", function(error, links) {

var nodes = {};

// Compute the distinct nodes from the links.
  links.forEach(function(link) {
      link.source = nodes[link.source] || 
         (nodes[link.source] = {name: link.source});
      link.target = nodes[link.target] || 
         (nodes[link.target] = {name: link.target});
      link.value = +link.value;
});
```

My code looks similar:

```
d3.csv("../assets/datastore/transitions.csv", function(error, data){
if(error) return console.warn(error);

var nodes = {};
data.forEach(function(d){console.log("This is the source " + d.source)});
//Compute distinct nodes from links
data.forEach(function(link){
    console.log("This is the source" + data.source);
    links.source = nodes[links.source] || (nodes[links.source] = {name: links.source});
    links.target = nodes[links.target] || (nodes[links.target] = {name: links.target})
    links.value = + links.value;
});
```

I even simplified my code, and tried to access just the most basic elements of the datum.

```
d3.csv("../assets/datastore/transitions.csv", function(error, data){
if(error) return console.warn(error);

var nodes = {};
data.forEach(function(d){console.log("This is the source " + d.source)})
```

Finally, it seems as if my data is being read, as I do have 81 elements registered as a node under the DOM when I use firebug.

If you could please hint at a potential solution, that would be great.

Comment: Please provide a sample of your CSV file.

Comment: betting you have spaces in your csv between column names/values.

Comment: You are absolutely correct. I had a space in my column name.  A very stupid mistake that took me a while to figure out! I ended up swapping csv files around, and figured out that the csv file had bad headers! If you write this as an answer I'll give it to you!

Comment: It happens. Answer written.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure your csv is formatted such that you delimit the values by comma, not by comma + space. It's a common mistake to impose the spacing delimitation standard, used in linguistic sentences, on data formats, as they are also syntactical.

Answer (score 0):

It seems possible that the `links` in the following code should be `link`;

```
links.source = nodes[links.source] || (nodes[links.source] = {name: links.source});
links.target = nodes[links.target] || (nodes[links.target] = {name: links.target})
links.value = + links.value;
```

Check that out first and see how it goes.

It looks like you're doing some good problem solving keep it up.

Comment: Unfortunately, this was not the solution. Further output displays: Data length is 81
network.js (line 34)
Data 0 is : undefined
network.js (line 36)
Data 1 is : undefined and links.source is This is the links source : undefined
network.js (line 45)
This is the sourceundefined

Comment: Maybe its an issue with my data formatting? My csv file looks as such: id, source, target, value
0,Node1,Node4,0
1,Node1,Node2,1231

Comment: I apologize for the poorly formatted comments, its hard to format an answer on the comment box in stackoverflow.

Comment: You could try to post your complete code and csv file as a Gist or similar to provide context?